# Cloudboost OrderByAsc on two columns

Tags: parse-platform, cloudboost, nosql

I'am using the OrderByAsc filter on two columns, do we have to do it with 2 instructions like :

```
query.orderByAsc('group');
query.orderByAsc('name');
```

Or can we do it like :

```
query.orderByAsc('group, name');
```

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, You should be doing it like

`query.orderByAsc('group');
query.orderByAsc('name');`

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it like this in Javascript:

`query.ascending("group,name");`